# Magento 2: Get root category ID programmatically in backend

Tags: magento2, category, backend

How can we get root category ID (Default Category) programmatically in backend ?

Answer (score 8):

Use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` class to get store default root category Id.

```
<?php
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $StoreManagerInterface)
    {
         $this->storeManagerInterface = $StoreManagerInterface;
    }



    public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it for backend ?

Comment: It will work anywhere.

Comment: I have put this code into the file but not working and break the site.

Comment: We put this code in block file but not working. After put this code site break.

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CategoryIdentifier
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface)
    {
         $this->storeManager = $storeManagerInterface;
    }

    public function getRootCategoryId(): int
    {
        // get store group id for current store
        $storeGroupId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreGroupId();
        // get root category id
        $rootCategoryId = $this->storeManager->getGroup($storeGroupId)->getRootCategoryId();
        return $rootCategoryId;
    }

}
```